# Can the amount of heavier elements in the Sun's core be approximated?

Tags: astrophysics, sun, hydrogen, fusion, metallicity

Can the amount of heavy and other types of elements as impurities inside the Sun's core be approximated?

If these elements are present, do they disturb the process of hydrogen fusion, since they occupy the center, which is the place of maximal pressure necessary for the fusion process? In particular, do these elements affect the rate of hydrogen fusion?

Comment: Search term: "standard solar model." See e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0412440) and [this supporting data](http://www.sns.ias.edu/~jnb/SNdata/sndata.html) from the late John Bahcall, though surely there is more recent work. Bahcall's interest was in the solar neutrino spectrum and his results seem to consider "metals" up to about fluorine.

Comment: The fusion of hydrogen is a very slow process, as I mentioned here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/540199/123208

Comment: Wikipedia has a [table of the abundances of the ten most common elements in the Milky Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements#Universe), and a more extensive list of the abundances of nuclides in our Solar System. Those numbers give us a reasonable first approximation of the element ratios present in the Sun at its birth, before it started converting hydrogen to helium.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_nucleosynthesis#Reaction_rate has some general information about stellar nuclear fusion reaction rates, but it's rather technical, and it doesn't mention the impact of impurities.

Comment: @rob Table 1 on p 3 here is prolly the best estimates for the photosphere, also summarized in my answer. Two comments above mentioned elemental quantities: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/375492/pdf

Comment: @PM2Ring Table 1 on p 3 here useful for that, estimates for the photosphere: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/375492/pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most recent effort to establish current elemental quantities in the sun’s photosphere that Im aware of is this article from 2003: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/375492/pdf

Table 1 on page 3 shows the estimate for the current sun, and later tables are protosolar. The first number is roughly natural log (For anyone new to that, think of it as someone reporting the exponent to you, giving you something akin to order of magnitude). The method used is indicated in about the fourth column. Anything with an a or an s has been verified as being present. I was surprised to see something so heavy as Rn (atomic number 86) in there and verified, albeit in minuscule amounts.

The order of elements for the first eight by number of atoms is; H, He, O, C, Ne, N, Mg, Si. Anything beyond that is over five orders of magnitude down. The photosphere is about 3/4 H, and is estimated to be 98.7% H and He, and the core is roughly that same total, but the H is higher as we go toward the center. At the core’s radius (at r= 0.2R), it is still approximately 70% H and decreases to about 1/3 H at the center. Source: http://solar-center.stanford.edu/helio-ed-mirror/english/engmod-res.html

Of note is the fact that the core is plasma, so no molecules are present. This is important. Chemical and moleculardynamic interactions slow nuclear reactions more than plasma does. There are no covalent bonding dynamics and far less molecular collision as the diameter of an atoms nucleus is as low as a millionth of the diameter of the same atom with its electron clouds. That said, nuclear reactions can still occur.

Aside from the main hydrogen fusions in the core (p-p I and to a much lesser extent p-pII), there is one called CNO which is almost two percent of the He production, and greater even than p-p III. Its primary catalysts are O, C, and N. However, most of the elements other than H and He, even in the core, are from the early universe. Hence they will be close to the proportions in the earth and especially the photosphere.

Actually, beyond O, C, Ne, and N, the quantities are low. The Mg content is around 8% of the O content. So one key question is whether around O and C in a plasma mixture would impede fusion. Based upon the effort needed to collide a proton into an oxygen by these researchers: https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218301316500609 I would say the proton cross-section of nuclei that size is negligible. The next step would be to check proton cross-sections for O16 etc as listed. Such as by accessing articles like this (paid): https://inspirehep.net/literature/107753

The reasoning here is that we know how much CNO is happening. We dont know how many other protons C and O are absorbing. Hence cross-sections could help. My guess is that they are only **aiding fusion** overall.

Similar sized nuclei are in the hundred millibarns range. While I havent done a calculation, at this point Im guessingg it wouldnt matter much, but “much” depends on research application and/or opinion, and is just an educated guess for now. And furthermore I think if anything the heavy elements overall are helping fusion.

Comment: I’m a little confused as to why you speculate that oxygen and carbon might “impede fusion,” while at the same time acknowledging that the [CNO-catalyzed fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNO_cycle) makes up about 2% of the Sun’s energy output. Since CNO collectively make up less than 2% of the mass density everywhere in the Sun, and therefore make up much, much less than 2% of the *number* density, it seems like those metals can only be abetting fusion, rather than hindering it.

Comment: Yeah in that little part I dont know anything. I wrote reactants but was thinking products. I should find out what CNO actually is. (But now I see in your link they are catalysts).  Also, the report I referenced refers to number density. Where did you get that CNO are less than 2% of mass, from what i wrote or elsewhere. But either way the number of them still seems low enough to not impede in any way more than help. I read somewhere that CNO is almost 2% of the helium generated. In short, youre right

Comment: @rob Ok i took out the talk about how c and o are the most prevalent in photosphere and also being produced making them even more. And added: The reasoning here is that we know how much CNO is happening. We dont know how many other protons C and O are absorbing. Hence cross-sections could help. My guess is that they are only **aiding fusion** overall. That was fun, thx comment

Comment: In the [Bahcall model](http://www.sns.ias.edu/~jnb/SNdata/sndata.html) that I linked in another comment, O-16 is about 0.6% mass fraction at all depths in the Sun. In that model C-12 and N-14 have lower mass fraction than O-16 at all depths, and the core is significantly carbon-depleted and nitrogen-enriched.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. You see in photosphere the order was O, C, Ne, N, Mg. First link, p3. But the Mg is a good drop from N. So maybe core is O, N, Ne, C, Mg depending on how depleted C is in core. But just a guess, is a quantitative question not qualitative. Either way the number density is low and c n o almost certainly help, which my answer now says. Im surprised such low amounts of c n and o make so much He in the core. Thats weird

Comment: "but the H is higher as we go toward the center." Mistake? You haven't addressed the abundance gradients, which *are* present in the Sun.

Comment: @ProfRob Yes typo for sure. Direct contradiction in one sentence. “but the H is **higher as we go toward the center**. At the core’s radius (at r= 0.2R), it is still approximately 70% H and **decreases to about 1/3 H at the center**.

Comment: @ProfRob Yes youre right. I focused on “In particular, do these elements affect the rate of hydrogen fusion?” And claimed the change in abundance is not the biggest factor in deciding that. That most of the change is to H and He.  “Hence they will be close to the proportions in the earth and especially the photosphere.”  I got in over my head on this one and just wrapped up. Id be very curious to see a another answer

Comment: The number density of heavier nuclei (relative to the density of H & He) isn't very relevant to p-p fusion. As I said [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/540199/123208), the main bottleneck in the proton-proton chain *isn't* the fusion of two protons to form a diproton, it's the conversion of the diproton to a deuteron.