Artificial Nucleosynthesis
Is it possible to artificially turn hydrogen into helium, let's say, and then go from helium to lithium and so on? I know that fusion reactors do that by fusing deuterium and tritium. Could this be a viable option to generate elements from other elements? Not in the sense of efficiency but rather in the sense of being able to produce reasonable amounts. Example: nitrogen to carbon.

Stars do this. It is quite difficult to do anywhere outside of stars.

The D-T reaction is quite amenable to being done in an ion implant system (providing you have one, as well as a tritiated target to send deuterium into).

What do you mean by "reasonable amounts"?

I mean in the sense of an industry being able to produce new elements like lithium for car batteries for example(i know that extracting lithium reserves is more cost efficient) but you get the point

@JonCuster you mean van de graaff atom smasher?

No - the cross section for D-T peaks around a 120 keV D ion into a tritium. Easily accessible by non-VdG machines. But it is an awfully expensive way to try and make a bit of He-4.

Transmuting chemically significant quantities of one element to another using nuclear reactions is not cost effective for any naturally occurring element. Nuclear physics is the end of alchemy..

Fusing plain hydrogen is very hard, even with stellar core temperature & pressure. As I said in https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/540199/123208  the mean time for a solar core proton to be successfully fused is around 9 billion years.


Is it possible to artificially turn hydrogen into helium, let's say,
and then go from helium to lithium and so on?

Yes, the conversion from one element to another is the basis of both nuclear fission and fusion.
Fission occurs naturally, but at a rate that makes it not very useful for industry. Nuclear reactors or linear accelerators are used to generate many additional neutrons which greatly increase the rate of these reactions to the point of being useful. Nuclear fuels like plutonium and medical isotopes like iodine-131 are produced using these processes and subsequent natural decay.
Heavier elements can be created from lighter ones via fusion. However, this process is very difficult to achieve. The first example was the creation of helium from deuterium in 1932 using a cyclotron, and today, almost 100 years later, we still don't use this process commercially. Ths is the process that occurs in the sun as well, which is constantly producing helium and heavier elements, but we don't have a sun's worth of material to work with in a factory so it's simply not practical.

It is possible in some circumstances, but the energy investment to do so is enormous and the quantities of material produced are tiny. It's far cheaper to dig holes in the ground in search of ore.
